# Using data from one select statement in another statement in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure which has multiple select statements in it. However, the second statement would use data which has been returned in the first statement to determine the second statement. Is this possible?

Example:

```
(Start loop)

Select ID, Value1, Value2 from table1

if Value 1 = Null then

Select Value2(taken from results of first select) from Table2

end if

(then loop through again)
```

I know this is a bit wishy washy but I just need to know if it is possible.

thanks for your help

Comment: Use MySQL procedures.

Comment: How would this be written in a mysql procedure?

Comment: See this https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843